# Upload Image from Android to GCS

Tags: android, file, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, uri

I picked a video from Android and tried to upload it to Google Cloud Storage.

This is my code:

```
Uri contentURI = data.getData();
String uri = contentURI.getPath();
Storage storage = (Storage) StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("red-provider 
 338704").build().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("resume-videos", "hello.mp4");
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(uri)));
```

When I run this code, I get a NoSuchFileException. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: `String uri = contentURI.getPath();` That is no path. Check with File.exists().

Comment: @blackapps It's coming as false. How do I get the file path then?

Comment: You will not try to get a file path. You dont need it. Use the uri.

Comment: I am still getting the NoSuchFileException.

Comment: @blackapps I tried getting the full path but I'm getting the AccessDeniedException error.

Comment: You will not try to get the full path. I said that before.